# How to write the output from diskpart to a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write the output from a `diskpart` command to a file, i.e., say something like

```
LIST PARTITION >c:\output.txt
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `/s` option to `diskpart`, i.e.,

```
diskpart /s scriptfile.txt > output.txt
```

where `scriptfile.txt` contains the command to be executed, i.e.,

```
LIST PARTITION
```