# get diskpart output to variable or on screen with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a command for diskpart -- run the script from a file myscript.txt in Powershell

diskpart /s myscript.txt

But when I execute this command through Powershell, it requesting permission to execute, then runs in a new window (this is cmd shell, not Powershell) and I cannot get its output.

Is it possible to get the output of this command and display it in the Powershell window?

Comment: It should be. You can use `Start-Process -verb runas` to start that diskpart, and also you can then get the process handle (which is returned by Start-Process) and plain retrieve its stdout and many other data about the process.

Comment: It seems to me that diskpart does not use stdout/stderr to output its data so it's not possible to capture it by reading stdout.

Comment: But there's an answer that it's possible to redirect its output in case of batch work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595611/how-to-write-the-output-from-diskpart-to-a-file

Comment: run powershell as administrator. Then diskpart will run within the powershell session and you can run a line like $rtrn=diskpart /s myscript.  BTW: there are cmdlets in powershell for all or most of the stuff you'd want to do with diskpart. So probably you don't need diskpart

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked!